# Color and Font declaration - stackoverflow error

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, colors, stack-overflow

I get a stackoverflow exception on following commented lines.

```
namespace Football_Manager_WFA
{    
    public partial class Settings : Form
    {
        Color def_bgdColor = SystemColors.Control;
        Color def_fontColor = Color.Black; // ERROR
        static FontFamily fontFamily = FontFamily.GenericSansSerif;
        Font def_fontType = new Font(fontFamily, 8.0f); // ERROR
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems very unlikely. Rebuild and post the exact stack trace (and the _exact_ code) if it persists.

Comment: When the exception happens, try to copy the text from VS.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Football Manager WFA.exe.` and this `{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}`

Comment: Try to open Details, we still don't know which line. And it can't be on 2 lines. But SO is notoriously difficult to catch.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: in details it is this {Cannot evaluate...}. I'm sorry, it gives me exception on def_fontColor. When I comment it out and rebuild it it throws it on the second one.

Comment: Where/How do you create that Settings form?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Right click, add new windows form?

Comment: I meant where do you instantiate and Show it?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Sorry. I don't understand your question. I show it on button click. Variable declarations are just before `public Settings(){InitializeComponent();}`

Comment: Post the ButtonClick to be sure. It looks like your Settings tries to create another Settings so check your code for other uses of the class.

Comment: If you are using visual studio debugger, go to Debug | Exceptions, and check the box next to IL Code.  This will cause the debugger to stop at the point of the exception.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: `Settings settingsForm;        private void settingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            settingsForm = new Settings();
            settingsForm.ShowDialog();
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, the problem wasn't in the line with the error.

I initialized Settings form on two places, two times.
So just deleted one of them and it works now. Thanks to Henk for a hint.